# React component to be displayed as a summation of 2 ajax calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, apollo-client

I am using react , Apollo client , hooks

I am wanting to make 2 separate ajax calls  , and once is get back the results of both the calls , I have to build a component with values retrieved from both the calls.

Is there any well know patterns to be followed for such use case.

Unfortunately, unable to combine the 2 graphql query in to 1.

Comment: Any reason you can't use `Promise.all()`?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you use apollo client. Basically saying you can use `Promise.all` like so

```
const [resultOne, resultTwo] = await Promise.all([
  client.query(query1),
  client.query(query2),
])
// then do something with this results
```

Syntax might not be correct but I hope you get the idea.

If you are using hooks you may write the query to include both queries likes so

```
const combinedQuery = gql`
  query CombinedQuery($params1: Params1!, $params2: Params2) {
     queryOne(params1: $params1) {
       field1
       field2
     }
     queryTwo(params2: $params2) {
       field1
       field2
     }

  }
`
```

and then use it like so

```
const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(combinedQuery, { variables: {...} })
```

Hope it will help.